# Picking the lines sharing certain columns ( but not all )

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, unique

I am trying to modify a file, that has `7` columns.
The input file example is :

```
1.txt
    1   10  11  A   L   X3  -1.1
    1   10  11  A   L   X1   1.1
    1   13  21  A   T   X3  -2.1
    3   11  12  A   T   X2  -3.1
    3   11  12  K   T   X2   7.1
    4   11  12  A   T   X7  -8.1
    4   11  12  C   T   X7  -8.1
    4   11  12  C   T   X7  11.1
```

I want to extract these lines that are sharing the first 5 columns, but differing in the last two and also the others which does not share the first 5 columns. And then, I want to keep the line with lowest value on the last column.

The expected output is:

```
    1   10  11  A   L   X3  -1.1
    1   13  21  A   T   X3  -2.1
    3   11  12  A   T   X2  -3.1
    3   11  12  K   T   X2   7.1
    4   11  12  A   T   X7  -8.1
    4   11  12  C   T   X7  -8.1
```

`1st line` is here because it shares the first `5` column with the `2.line` in the `1.txt` file. And it has the lowest number on the last column (`-1.1 < 1.1` and also for the last line, we keep the one with `-8.1` as it is smaller than `11.1`), so we only keep it, and we keep the other lines that does not have identical first `5` fields with each other.
What I have tried is keeping the first `5` column as `index` in `awk`, but it only prints the unique ones, not the rest. And it does not pick for the line having a lowest number in the last column.
The code:

```
awk -F"\t" '!seen[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5]++' 1.txt
```

Its output:

```
1   10  11  A   L   X3  -1.1
1   10  11  A   L   X1   1.1
1   13  21  A   T   X3  -2.1
3   11  12  A   T   X2  -3.1
3   11  12  K   T   X2   7.1
4   11  12  A   T   X7  -8.1
4   11  12  C   T   X7  -8.1
4   11  12  C   T   X7  11.1
```

I cannot pick the lines that are sharing only the first `5` columns, that have the lowest value on last column.
Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    {key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5} 
    !(key in min) || $NF < min[key] {min[key] = $NF; line[key] = $0} 
    END {for (key in line) print line[key]}
' file
```

```
    1   10  11  A   L   X3  -1.1
    1   13  21  A   T   X3  -2.1
    4   11  12  C   T   X7  -8.1
    4   11  12  A   T   X7  -8.1
    3   11  12  K   T   X2   7.1
    3   11  12  A   T   X2  -3.1
```

Note the order of the output is indeterminate. You can always pipe the output to `sort`, or use GNU awk and control the [array traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html).

---

I just realized the `line` array is completely unnecessary but will consume a lot of memory: The `min` array holds the first 5 fields as the key and the 6th field as the value

```
awk '
    {key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5} 
    !(key in min) || $NF < min[key] {min[key] = $NF} 
    END {for (key in line) print key, min[key]}
' file
```

It might be taking so long due to swapping.

Comment: How did you choose according to value on the last column? Is it possible that you can explain?

Comment: I keep track of the minimum value for the last column: `$NF < min[key]`

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to make it faster? My input file is huge, and it takes so much time..

Comment: It is around 50Million

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue! (with the help of `sort`)

```
$ sort -k1,5 -k7n file | 
  awk '!a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5]++'


1   10  11  A   L   X3  -1.1
1   13  21  A   T   X3  -2.1
3   11  12  A   T   X2  -3.1
3   11  12  K   T   X2   7.1
4   11  12  A   T   X7  -8.1
4   11  12  C   T   X7  -8.1
```

sort groups the records with the shared key (fields 1 to 5) and rank them by the seventh field numerically ascending (so the first one is with the minimum value); piped into `awk` to pick up the first record for the given key (the famous `awk` idiom, you also used in your script).

Here is another approach without `awk`

```
$ sort -k1,5 -k7n file | rev | uniq -f2 | rev
```

Comment: Is it possible that you can explain a bit please?

Comment: But then, if I want to for example sort it by not first consecutive columns,  but with column 1 and 4 and 5, how do I do it?

Comment: the  `uniq` solution will not work if the keys are not contiguous.  `sort/awk` pair will work if you set the keys correctly for both.